# Asynchronous methods and a event

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, awesomium

I use awesomium to automate a site. I tried to use asynchronous programming, because I didn't want my GUI to freeze, but I have a problem at a event (a popup appear and I want to make some actions in this popup until I close it) when the application doesn't continue how I want. After the event is fired I want my application to continue with the event method (webc_ShowCreatedWebView and after with popupTwitter(method), but I find that when executing JavaScript code, the control returns in the While from the first method. How could I do that after the earnpoints method is called and the events is fired to finish the event and the method and after that the control return in the while.

```
  private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Twitter twitter = new Twitter(webView);
        twitter.Login(webView);
        webView.ShowCreatedWebView += webc_ShowCreatedWebView;
        addmefast.Login(webView);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            Task earnpoints = EarnPoints(webView);
            await earnpoints;
            //Here i don't want to continue until EarnPoints method > webc_ShowCreatedWebView event > popupTwitter method it's finished.
            i++;
        }
    }

    public async Task EarnPoints(IWebView web)
    {
        web.Source = "http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter".ToUri();
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        web.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('single_like_button btn3-wrap')[0].click();"); //event fired: webc_ShowCreatedWebView
    }

    async void webc_ShowCreatedWebView(object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView view = new WebView(e.NewViewInstance);
        await popupTwitter(view);
    }

   async Task popupTwitter(WebView view)
    {
        Popupform FormTwitter = new Popupform(view);
        FormTwitter.Show();
       await  Task.Delay(6000);
        FormTwitter.Twitter();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        FormTwitter.Close();
        await  Task.Delay(4000);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like awesomium doesn't understand asynchronous events. If that's the case, there really isn't anything you can do other than ask them to support async.

Comment: It looks to me like webc_ShowCreatedWebView will only be fired after EarnPoints already returned. May be you could you use EventWaitHandle and only set it in the popupTwitter method. The while loop will block till the EventWaitHandle is set.
MSDN docs: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems implementing async methods with awesomium, but got it working.

First I made this wrapper.  Have to be created on the main thread.

```
public class AsyncWebView
{

    public static SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;
    private readonly WebView _webView;

    public AsyncWebView()
    {
        _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        _webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 900);
    }

    public async Task Navigate(String url)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Navigating");
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        FrameEventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(args.Url);

            if (!_webView.IsNavigating && !_webView.IsLoading)
                tcs.SetResult(true);
        };

        _webView.LoadingFrameComplete += handler;

        _synchronizationContext.Send(SetWebViewSource, url);

        await tcs.Task;

        _webView.LoadingFrameComplete -= handler;

        Debug.WriteLine("Done");

    }

    private void SetWebViewSource(object url)
    {
        _webView.Source = new Uri((string)url);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
async Task test()
{
    await webView.Navigate("http://www.nytimes.com");
    Debug.WriteLine("All done");
}
```

Just make sure you have a SynchronizationContext where the AsyncWebView constructor is called from.